# Sending an Email Using Java

Tags: java, email, servlets

```
 try{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "ipc-smtp.bits-pilani.ac.in");
        Session sess = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        sess.setDebug(true);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(sess);
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("mymail@gmail.com"));
        msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");
        msg.setSubject("Test");
        msg.setContent("Yippe", "text/plain");
        Transport.send(msg);
        }catch(Exception exp){
           exp.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The error is javax.mail.MessagingException: 554 The mail was blocked due to zen-spamhaus RBL action

This is my college's smtp server.

Comment: This is a spam issue, it has nothing to do with java sending mail.The SMTP server's IP address is being blocked as a spammer.

Comment: What is your question?  The only thing I can deduce is that you're wondering what the Zen Spamhaus RBL is and why it's blocking your email, in which case this isn't programming-related... and I'd posit that Google can answer that for you. :)

Comment: I tried sending an email using my college email to my college email, then also the same error comes
That would mean, that this server is blocking its own emails??

Anyways, any other smtp servers that i can try?

Comment: I looking for this ways to correct this code, I tried smtp.gmail.com but that needs authentication, and that didn't work out.

Comment: Create an smtp server on your own machine to verify that your code is correct.  It's reasonable that the smtp servers you tried would not allow arbitrary machines to relay mail, so the errors you see are not surprising.

Comment: I did..now the error changed to 

javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Comment: @delfuego: [Don't tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43879/anti-tags-valid-use-or-not) [not-programming-related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag/10222#10222)

Answer (score 1):

I would inform your college's IT dept and they should be able to handle the issue. Although since it appears they left an open relay, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.mail.*;    
import javax.mail.internet.*;
```

.....

```
public static void postMail(String[] recipients, String subject, String message, String from) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", Util.getProperty("smtpHost"));
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
    }
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
    //msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(message, "text/html");
    Transport.send(msg);
}
```